Old management game in which you could send fairy critters to do work, like chopping down trees and building a house
Roughly in 2005-2008 I was playing a game, but I remember very little about it and I've been looking for it since forever.
What I remember:

Might have been a DVD/online game, it ran on Windows XP machine.
It involved management; you could send fairy critters (they might have been similar to Ori from Ori and the Blind Forest) to do some work, like chopping down trees and building a house (not sure, but I think it was as so).
Setting: fairy, purple forest (might be also wrong, but I think my memory is not failing me here).
It was 2.5D; you looked at it from god perspective.
I was in Central Europe at the time, Czechia to be more specific. I do not remember the game having much text, so I cannot remember if it was in Czech or English.

Sorry for the description not being the best, but I was quite young at the time.

Not Harvest Moon, right? It would've been via emulation, not a PC native game. I never played much of the series, and I'm pretty sure the trees wouldn't be purple, but it does give you helpers later on and I recall them being fairies.

This sounds like it could be Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos. Specifically the Night Elf campaign.
Warcraft 3 is an RTS game originally released in 2002 for PC.
The Night Elf faction specifically used a minion unit called a wisp that magically teleported resources to the base rather than mechanically chopping and transporting materials.
It looked like a moving ball of magic fairy dust.

Buildings were created by sacrificing a wisp (plus resources) to construct the new building. Many of which looked like trees and could later be uprooted and slow-walked to new locations.
A lot of the early night elf levels had a green/purple aesthetic.
Generally looked like this;


This was my first thought, as well.

This seems like the closest I will get to an answer, thank you! ^^

@JuliaP. Only mark it right if it is right. :) While older questions don't always get a lot of traffic sometimes someone does come along, but they're unlikely to submit a new answer if there's an accepted one already.
